# Docker API - how to create image

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to create a Docker Image using the V2 Docker API for Python.

Here's what I have:

```
DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL= "https://docker-images.cyber.local/v2"

def createTestContainer():
    imageObject = {'image': 'nginx',
                   'Hostname': 'purger-script-test',
                   'Domainname': "purger-script-test"
                  }
    createContainer = requests.post(f"{DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL}/image/create", data = imageObject, verify=False)
    print(createContainer)
```

I tried several other ways, and I can't create a new image in the registry. Help please.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dangminhtruong/5c95ebe220584d3e0429c05549b98175

Comment: What is the detail of `print(createContainer)` ?

Comment: @grimur82 <Response [404]>

Comment: why not to use docker-py ?

Comment: The URL of the POST request should be `{DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL}/images/create` (missed an s) that's why you get a 404 code (not found)

Comment: @b0gusb I tried also with "images" - same 404 result.

Comment: Make sure your docker registry is running and you have access to it

Comment: @Neekoy I think there is a bit of confusion. If you wish to push an image using the docker [Registry API V2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#pushing-an-image) the URL has the format `/v2/<name>/blobs/uploads/`. If instead you push 
using the [Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.20/#22-images)) the format is different `/images/(name)/push`. To create an an image, either by pulling it from the registry or by importing it, the URL is `/images/create`